# Google Maps API Won't SHOW ICONS

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Perfect!

These websites won't populate the icons on the Google Maps I've added an API to make sure it does,

http://www.laketonopahliving.com/community

But these website does and doesn't have an api:

http://www.1001melroseapts.com/community

What do I need to do some the above link map will look like the bottom link map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need an array of markers that you can add to the map.

Ideally the marker locations would be added to a DB where you can store the latitude and longitutde for each marker point, as the latitude and longitude is what Google uses to place the markers on the map.

So if you had an array of locations like the following:

```
var locations = [
    {lat: 38.1234324, lng: 78.123234, name: "Test 1", id:1},
    {lat: 39.1234324, lng: 79.123234, name: "Test 2", id:2},
    {lat: 40.1234324, lng: 80.123234, name: "Test 3", id:3},
    {lat: 41.1234324, lng: 81.123234, name: "Test 4", id:4}
]
```

You would then loop over the array and add the markers to the map with something like this:

```
$.each(locations, function(idx, location) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
            position : new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng),
            title: location.name,
            map: map //map is the map object instance
    });
});
```